# Inserir novo campo customizado em Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

Estou customizando um site que foi feito em Wordpress. Em uma parte específica do site, na EQUIPE, há uma foto de uma pessoa e ao lado é para ser adicionada um campo de texto. O que acontece, é que no tema em que o site foi desenvolvido não há essa opção. Na verdade, a opção EQUIPE é bem limitada. Eu gostaria de saber se há como eu criar um novo campo personalizado para isso, e que esse campo tenha o conteúdo para ser exibido no site (Front-End).[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Member é um Custom Post Type? Como foram criados os campos que já existem, no código ou usando plugin?

Comment: Já existe no tema.